# An error when trying to copy a file from the assets folder

Tags: android, file, assets

I am trying to copy a file from assets folder to external storage, this is the code I have:

```
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imgs/" + str2);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream ins = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("imgs/" + str2);
                FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len=ins.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                ins.close();
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);
            }
        }
```

but the error I get is:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/imgs/pic_name.jpg (No such file or directory)`

But, I am creating this file so I have no idea why it says that it's not found.

Comment: Please identify the line of code that throws the exception and also post the full stack trace.

Comment: In addition to Amrnoid's point regarding creating the directory, you need to request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (including the runtime request), if you are not already doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because "img" directory is not exists you must create the directory

code:

```
   String rootPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/imgs/";
        File file=new File(rootPath);
      if(!file.exists()){
         file.mkdirs();
       }
```