# java.lang.String java.io.File.getName() null object reference in android

Tags: android

I have used bellow code for getting file name. **android 7, API 25  working, android 6.0, API 23 is not working**. Here is my code

```
 File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myfolder");
 File audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, audioFileExtention, sampleDir);
audiofile.getName()
```

But when i run it shows bellow error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getName()' on a null object reference
```

But it is working fine in some devices.I have used bellow code for gadle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {       
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }
 }
```

I don't know why it shows error. Please help me

Comment: Did you implemented `Runtime Permission` for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical yes sir

Comment: Can you post the file_name and audioFileExtension?

Comment: @kAliert   audioFileExtention = ".mp3"; android 7 api label 25 working, android 6 api 23 is not working

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996279/10738439

Comment: try to add `sampleDir.mkdir();` before `File audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, audioFileExtention, sampleDir);`. because it might possible `File.createTempFile()` throws Exception with error "No Such file or Directory" as **sampleDir** is not available on storage.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical  i have already done it but  File.createTempFile(file_name, audioFileExtention, sampleDir) returns null